# d3.js v5 - d3.json reads file locally on windows but not on linux?

Tags: d3.js

My code works fine locally, attempted to convert the json from windows to unix format and the file gets put into a war file for deployment - after which I cannot seem to read the file (same issue occured with a csv file too), seems to exit the Promise as undefined - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
sovereignBondsPortlet.js:144 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined
    at sovereignBondsPortlet.js:144


  var dataset = d3.json("50m_unix.json").then(function(data) {
        return data;
  }).catch(console.log.bind(console));

  var worldjson = dataset.then(function(world) {

    var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

    topo = countries;
    draw(topo);
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL `50m_unix.json` actually returns the resource? Did you try opening it yourself? The `Unexpected token <` makes me think you're returned an HTML, maybe even with a 404 error. Your issue could lie with your backend, not d3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Coderino said, you probably got some sort of server error. You might be able to get more details through Chrome dev tools, which is a great way to debug and troubleshoot your code.

1. Open the page using chrome.
2. Open up Chrome dev tools. There's many ways to do it. For more information, refer to the [Google documentation on it](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open).
3. Click on the `network` tab.
4. Refresh the page
5. Click on the request for the JSON. It'd have the name starting with `50m_unix.json`.
6. From there, you can look at various information including preview, response, status, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on using the Network tools from Chrome - I see this error: Error 400: EJPSD0020E: The WAS request URL cookie was not found. Either cookies are not enabled in the used browser or the Servlet is being directly accessed. - Any thoiughts ???

Comment: Directory path needed to be wired from jsp to the js